# Why do we use <?php and then ?> on every single line?

Tags: joomla-coding-standards

It seems like there is a new code convention that I haven't noticed previously.

On every PHP line it is opened and closed like

```
<?php echo "some stuff"; ?>
<?php echo "other stuff"; ?>
<?php echo "more stuff"; ?>
```

It would make as much sense to do

```
<?php 
      echo "some stuff"; 
      echo "other stuff"; 
      echo "more stuff"; 
?>
```

What is the reason for this way of coding?  I'm sure there is one, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mentioned in Joomla! Coding Standards Manual:

> For layout files and all files where we use a mix of PHP and HTML (all PHP files in the `view/tmpl` and `layout` folder) we additionally wrap every line into a `<?php ... ?>` block and use the alternative syntax for control structures.

The reasoning is this:

> This should make the code easier to read and make it easier to move blocks around without creating fatal errors due to missing `<?php ... ?>` tags.

https://developer.joomla.org/coding-standards/php-code.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more of a PHP coding standards question than Joomla question. So I’d only like to give a short answer on this.

If someone closes PHP code at every line then it is a bad coding style or bad understanding of PHP. If the file is a mixed file with PHP/HTML then the line has to be closed with `?>` before using HTML of course.

For PHP there is PSR. PSR stands for **PHP Standard Recommendation**. You can study the basic coding style guide for example here:

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Only few excerpts from the recommendations:

**PHP Tags:**

> PHP code MUST use the long `<?php ?>` tags or the short-echo `<?= ?>` tags; it MUST NOT use the other tag variations.

**On PHP files:**

> The closing `?>` tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP.

PHP standard recommendation is not a must but it is a well considered convention among PHP programmers.

So the answer on your question is: there is no any convention in PHP for closing every line with PHP closing tag.

(Short edit: since @sharky copied few lines from Joomla coding standards in his answer which gives that in Joomla layout files every line should be closed with PHP closing tags (then open and close again in every line), well, I think, even if this is recommended in Joomla, I think it is not practical at all and does not help moving PHP code blocks at all...but I was then a bit wrong above specifically regarding Joomla layout coding style, since someones decided to recommend this style. The use of that style might be reconsidered though according to me, I do not see any real, valuable reasoning behind using that...but maybe it is just my opinion).

And as I see in other posts it is not only frowned upon by me but other PHP developers are  also agains this with their bad opinions (well, in other frameworks):

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/79938/why-have-php-and-on-every-line

Comment: Ah yes, I think this is more to do with `if` statements and `endif` rather than `{` curly brackets.  It just means you keep HTML outside of PHP.

Comment: Well, @sharky cleared the question more in his answer...